# Does gensim.corpora.Dictionary have term frequency saved?

Tags: python, dictionary, frequency, gensim, tf-idf

**Does gensim.corpora.Dictionary have term frequency saved?**

From [`gensim.corpora.Dictionary`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html), it's possible to get the document frequency of the words (i.e. how many document did a particular word occur in):

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

documents = brown.sents()
brown_dict = Dictionary(documents)

# The 100th word in the dictionary: 'these'
print('The word "' + brown_dict[100] + '" appears in', brown_dict.dfs[100],'documents')
```

[out]:

```
The word "these" appears in 1213 documents
```

And there is the [`filter_n_most_frequent(remove_n)`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.filter_n_most_frequent) function that can remove the n-th most frequent tokens:

> `filter_n_most_frequent(remove_n)`
>   Filter out the ‘remove_n’ most frequent tokens that appear in the documents.
>
> After the pruning, shrink resulting gaps in word ids.
>
> Note: Due to the gap shrinking, the same word may have a different word id before and after the call to this function!

**Is the `filter_n_most_frequent` function removing the n-th most frequent based on the document frequency or term frequency?**

If it's the latter, **is there some way to access the term frequency of the words in the `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` object?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` does not save term frequency. You can [see the source code here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py). The class only stores the following member variables:

```
    self.token2id = {}  # token -> tokenId
    self.id2token = {}  # reverse mapping for token2id; only formed on request, to save memory
    self.dfs = {}  # document frequencies: tokenId -> in how many documents this token appeared

    self.num_docs = 0  # number of documents processed
    self.num_pos = 0  # total number of corpus positions
    self.num_nnz = 0  # total number of non-zeroes in the BOW matrix
```

This means everything in the class defines frequency as document frequency, never term frequency, as the latter is never stored globally. This applies to `filter_n_most_frequent(remove_n)` as well as every other method.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same simple question.   It appears that the frequency of the word is hidden and not accessible in the object.   Not sure why it makes testing and validation a pain. What I did was export the dictionary as text..

```
dictionary.save_as_text('c:\\research\\gensimDictionary.txt')
```

In that text file they have three columns..   For example here are the words "summit" "summon" and "sumo"

Key     Word    Frequency

10      summit  1227

3658    summon  118

8477    sumo    40

I found a solution the .cfs are the word frequencies..       see https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary

```
print(str(dictionary[10]), str(dictionary.cfs[10]))
```

summit 1227

simple

Answer (score 4):

`gensim.corpora.Dictionary` now has term frequency stored in its `cfs` attribute. You can see the [documentation here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.cfs).

> cfs
> Collection frequencies: token_id -> how many instances of this token are contained in the documents.
> Type: dict of (int, int)

Answer (score 2):

Could you do something like this?

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(documents)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(sent) for sent in documents]
vocab = list(dictionary.values()) #list of terms in the dictionary
vocab_tf = [dict(i) for i in corpus]
vocab_tf = list(pd.DataFrame(vocab_tf).sum(axis=0)) #list of term frequencies
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary does not have it, but corpus does.

```
# Term frequency
# load dictionary
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load('YourDict.dict')
# load corpus
corpus = corpora.MmCorpus('YourCorpus.mm')
CorpusTermFrequency = array([[(dictionary[id], freq) for id, freq in cp] for cp in corpus])
```

Answer (score 0):

one efficient way to calculate term-frequency from *bow* representation rather than creating dense vectors.

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(sent) for sent in documents]
vocab_tf={}
for i in corpus:
    for item,count in dict(i).items():
        if item in vocab_tf:
            vocab_tf[item]+=count
        else:
            vocab_tf[item] = count
```